# How does Gauss's lemma follow from Nagata's lemma?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

In section 4 of Samuel's [Unique Factorization](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/PierreSamuel.pdf) it's said Gauss's lemma is an easy consequence of [Nagata's lemma](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AFU). How to deduce Gauss's lemma from Nagata's lemma?

I'm asking because Nagata's lemma help to determine when irreducibles are primes, yet Gauss's lemma does not assume anything about irreducibility in $\mathbb Z[x]$ but rather obtains it from $\mathbb Q[x]$ and primitivity, a property that doesn't seem to fit in...

Answer (score 1):

By Gauss' lemma he means the fact that if $A$ is factorial, then so is $A[T]$.
Samuel explains the proof in his paper.... namely let $S=A-\{0\}\subset A[T]$. Then $S$ is generated by prime elements, and $S^{-1}A[T]=\mathrm{Frac}(A)[T]$ is a PID, hence factorial. Thus $A[T]$ is itself factorial.

Comment: I was hoping he meant the usual formulation where you touch irreducibility of polynomials. Is there any way to recover it from the general result?

Comment: @Arrow to understand what you mean by Gauss lemma: is it the fact that a polynomial with Z coefficients is irreducible over Z iff primitive+irreducible over Q? I will need to think harder for this one, but I imagine that one should be able to prove this as well.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I mean!